# How to get the red channel color space of an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get the red channel color space of an image, currently the way I'm doing it, I get a `grayscale` image:

```
img = img[:,:,2]
```

But I want an image like this:

[image]

Above, the top image is the red channel color space image, and the bottom one is the original image.  What exactly is being done to achieve this image?

I've also tried

```
img[:,:,0] = 0
img[:,:,1] = 0
```

But the result obtained is not as desired. Here's an article on red channel color space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RG_color_space

Comment: You probably just need to set the blue channel to 0 in the original BGR image: `img[:,:,0] = 0`

Comment: I've tried it, but the result is very different from that in the imgur link.

Comment: It seems to me that the color channel that is removed is not the red one, but a mix of green and blue. I suggest you to open the image in InkScape (or any other picture processing software), and play with the color levels. Once you identified the correct combination, remove the reminder.

Comment: My guess is too, that your first image was computed with a color map. Where did you get that first image from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your expected output image is not the red channel color space of the original one. It's sort of a *COLORMAP* that has been applied on input image. The good news is that OpenCV come up with multiple built-in colormaps. The bad news is that your expected output cant be generate by OpenCV's built-in colormaps. But don't give up, you can map the colors using a custom lookup table using [`cv2.LUT()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) function.

For better demonstration here are some examples with your image:

```
img = cv2.imread('origin.png')
im_color = cv2.applyColorMap(img, cv2.COLORMAP_HSV)
cv2.imshow('mapped_image', im_color)
# cv2.imwrite('result.png', im_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Here are all the OpenCV's COLORMAP's:

```
print [sub for sub in dir(cv2) if sub.startswith('COLORMAP_')]
['COLORMAP_AUTUMN', 'COLORMAP_BONE', 'COLORMAP_COOL', 'COLORMAP_HOT', 'COLORMAP_HSV', 'COLORMAP_JET', 'COLORMAP_OCEAN', 'COLORMAP_PINK', 'COLORMAP_RAINBOW', 'COLORMAP_SPRING', 'COLORMAP_SUMMER', 'COLORMAP_WINTER']
```

An example for mapping the colors using a custom lookup table using [`cv2.LUT()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut):

```
table = np.array([( i * invert_value) for i in np.arange(256)]).astype("uint8")
cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

Comment: Excellent. But `cv2.LUT()` will give me an array, Am I supposed t construct a colormap or something? If no, of what use is the output array of `cv2.LUT()`?

Comment: @stack Every Image is an array :-) but you need to convert it to a proper type in order to be able to identified as an image by OpenCV. let me Update the answer with an example.

Comment: @stack Also note that you might want to do some process on the result of one of the built-in `COLORMAP`s in order to convert it to your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your second suggestion should throw away the blue and green colors and give you a "red channel image". If you want a `RG` (red-green) color space image, throw away only the blue channel:

```
img[:,:,0] = 0
```

But the example image you posted doesn't illustrate that, as the resulting image has information left in all three channels. My guess is that it was produced with a "colormap", where different colors represent different values of red in the original image. Such a mapping can look any way you like, so it's not easy to reconstruct it from your example images